# How to set initial map location in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to set initial location on map to the coordinate I get from user profile stored in database say userLocation. I call `GMSCameraPosition` in `viewDidLoad` but have noticed that simulator detects current location and centers the map on it rather than location I am trying to set. I can see map positioned on `userLocation` briefly but immediately moves to current location.

I am even calling `stopUpdatingLocation` method but no success.

Does `stopUpdatingLocation` call location update once before stopping? That's what it appeared to me when I traced using breakpoints!

And does `GMSCameraPosition` also change underlying coordinates or just focus in the coordinate provided?

Below is the code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    mapView.delegate = self

    if userLocation != nil {

        mapView.myLocationEnabled = false
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: selectedCoordinate!.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
    } 

}

extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {

            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }

}

extension MapViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {

        reverseGeocodeCoordinate(position.target)

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add :-

`locationManager. stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` after `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`

Also Mind that `CLLocationManagerDelegate` is an `asynchronously` run class protocol which means once you execute line `mapView.delegate = self`, you have initialised your delegate to `self` which will send a call to fetch `usersCurrentLocation` geoCoordinates which means it will check if it's protocols Delegate methods are conformed in that particular class , Because if they are then it will call those methods irrespective of wether or not you have called `stopUpdatingLocation()`.

So solution :-

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

   if userLocation != nil {



    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: selectedCoordinate!.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
} else if let location = locations.first {

         mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

         locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used a flag to achieve same but your answer is cleaner.

Comment: I am facing another issue. map randomly opens <+51.17889992,-1.82639994> coordinates. Below are some print statement output 
MapViewCoontroller - idleAtCameraPosition - Location : CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.17889991879489, longitude: -1.8263999372720716)

MapViewCoontroller - didUpdateLocations - Location selected: Optional(<+51.17889992,-1.82639994>

MapViewCoontroller - didUpdateLocations - Location selected: Optional(<+51.17889992,-1.82639994>

Comment: Then what are they, current location?

Comment: <+18.49655889,+73.81614894> is my actual location. I am testing on iphone 6. Noticed it randomly moves to those 51.1788, -1.8263. I have unwind segue using which return coordinates from MapViewController and when i come back to MapViewController, sometimes shows 18,73 and sometimes 51,-1.8

Comment: Pls check https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzkAK4mdCMziMjVZeHRCa2ZzVFE i have done some to and fro between profile and map view controllers. it went to 51,-1.8 on line 39

Comment: I dont have enough reputations for chat it seems.

Comment: anyways Can you upload to git and share the link?

Comment: I have GitHub account. Do I have to create a repository  or can upload file without it ? Pardon me as I haven't done this before.

Comment: Hi @ashishn , though it is late did you found the scenario of that weird latitude and longitude? Seems the same lat/long we are getting at a very rare scenario.